# ASP.net Linkbutton with onclick event in codebehind not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp linkbutton in a navigation drop down list. It will be used for logging out and so I have an event linked to the code behind, where I shall close and empty the session. But when I startup my project it gives this error:

> CS1061: 'ASP.main_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'LinkButton_Click' and no extension method 'LinkButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.main_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is my aspx code

```
<li><asp:LinkButton id="myLink" Text="Logout" OnClick="LinkButton_Click" runat="server"/></li>
```

and this is the code behind code

```
void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

**Problem :** You should specify `protected` access modifier for `LinkButton` `Click` Event otherwise by default access modifier `private` will be applied and `LinkButton` Click event function can not be accessed. that is why t=you are getting the following Exception

> 'ASP.main_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'LinkButton_Click'......

**Solution :** add `protected` as `access-modifier` for your `LinkButton` `Click` event in the code behind file

Try This :

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Session.Clear();
   Session.RemoveAll();
   Session.Abandon();
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found it, I made a silly mistake. I made this OUTSIDE of my form elements with the runatserver in it.